# Redirecting requested url from old to new site (different domain name)

Tags: dns, hosting

I have a Wordpress website located on a windows server.  The performance is terrible.  The domain ends with ".net".  I also own the ".com" version of the domain name.  I have purchased a Linux hosting package and have set up the ".com" domain on it.  I have transferred all of the ".net" files to the ".com" host.  I have 150 email addresses setup on ".net" that I want to keep there (for now).  I want to have it so that any links in the wild to specific pages (ie http://www.mysite.net/p=123) go to the same page on the new site (http://www.mysite.com/p=123).  I am assuming I would just delete all of the files from the ".net" domain space, and then have a 404 file that captures the url requested and redirects to the ".com" equivalent.  Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My host allows custom 404 pages and so what I did was delete everything from the old server and then have my 404 say:

```
<?php
$qs = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = substr($qs, strpos($qs, ':80')+3);
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
include('index.php');
header( 'Location: http://www.mysite.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ;
?>
```

This works!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should solve your problem.

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F

a .htaccess in the root with this as the content:

```
Redirect 301 / http://mysite.com/
```

This should just blindly redirect all requests from the .net version to the .com, assuming that they have the same paths

Comment: Thank you for your answer but Windows doesn't use .htaccess files and the host does not allow ISAPI rewrites.